# Почему данные пишутся в базу данных неверно?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот структура БД

[image: структура БД]
Данные которые пишу находятся в ассоциативном массиве
Вот пример
    `array(6) {
    ["post-id"]=>
    string(29) "1510849007681248963_196691920"
    ["post-url"]=>
    string(40) "https://www.instagram.com/p/BT3nSrsF57D/"
    ["post-author"]=>
    string(13) "rousvel_fifth"
    ["post-date"]=>
    string(10) "1494327258"
    ["pic-url"]=>
    string(109) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/18382713_118552792048179_6482017612954861568_n
.jpg"
    ["post-text"]=>
    string(7) "#coffee"
    }`

Пишу вот так

```
`foreach($selected_pictures as $item) {
        $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . "plugin_soc_hshtgs_fndr",
                    array('post_id'=>$item["post-id"],
                          'post_url'=>$item["post-url"],
                          'post_author'=>$item["post-author"],
                          'post_creation_date'=>$item["post-date"],
                          'post_text'=>$item["post-text"],
                          'post_photo_url'=>$item["pic-url"],
                          'soc_ntwrk_id'=>"ins")
                     );
    }`
```

А вот что в БД попадает
[image: Результат]

Причем post-id не совпадает с тем что я пишу и постоянно одинаковый независимо от данных, post-author постоянно пустой, post-date постоянно пустой.

Comment: Зачем искать приключений на седалище и почему не использовать правильные средства? Напр wp_insert_post.

Comment: Вставка идет не постов. Это код из плагина. Там данные из социальных сетей.

Comment: Для "не постов" тоже есть правильные функции. А лазить в базу - самое последнее дело. И только тогда когда ОЧЕНЬ хорошо знаешь и понимаешь что откуда куда как происходит в ВП.

Comment: Приведите лучший способ. Формулировка "правильные функции" расплывчата.

Comment: А "не постов" -  это чёткая формулировка? Все функции есть тут https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/

Comment: Хорошо, сформулирую более четко. Я пишу произвольные данные в созданную таблицу в БД в плагине. Ссылку на документацию я и без вашего комментария знаю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58881/discussion-between-supply-and-sevlad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему нельзя использовать поля с имена post_id, post_author т.к. они зарезервированы в WordPress. Добавил префиксы к именам полей в БД и данные стали записываться нормально. Дату перед записью необходимо конвертировать

```
'plgn_post_creation_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $item['insta-post-date'])
```